# REST API from Javascript - Invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: parse-platform

new Parse developer here looking for some help.

I'm trying to call the REST API from my app to log custom analytics, but for some reason the XMLHttpRequest I'm making fails with the error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.parse.com/1/events/marker. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Here is the code I am using to make the request:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://api.parse.com/1/events/marker", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id","appidhere");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key","apikeyhere");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xmlhttp.send('{"dimensions":{"action":"showDetails"}}');
```

This is the console output:

```
OPTIONS https://api.parse.com/1/events/marker  (index):3639(anonymous function) (index):3639S.trigger main.js:15(anonymous function) VM625:31(anonymous function) VM623:11S.trigger main.js:15L.zc VM622:132L.nn VM622:132(anonymous function) main.js:13S.trigger main.js:15L.kl VM622:116(anonymous function) main.js:16
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.parse.com/1/events/marker. Invalid HTTP status code 405`
```

The strangest thing though is that when I make the request using the curl example in the documentation it works perfectly fine. :/ Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Hoping it's something simple that I'm overlooking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 405 error is [Method Not Allowed](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html).  The resource you're trying to hit does not accept the POST method.

Be *certain* that the resource you're trying to hit supports POST; if it doesn't, you'll have to change your XMLHttpRequest accordingly.